# Trying to use form entry to set variables that are used to create a custom URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, variables, concatenation

I'm working on a project internally that is rather over my head in terms of coding.  I've been teaching myself as I go to build a website resource for employees as a proof of concept for a larger project, and I have virtually no experience with JavaScript.

I'm trying to allow people to use a form to enter/select values for variables vara, varb, and varc.  After entering that info, I want them to be able to look through a list of items that I'm allowing them to filter, and when they find the one they want they click on a button that combines the variables in a query string with some additional text in between them and goes to that website.

The URL with the query string would need to look like:

http://www.websiteurl.com/website.aspx?T=12345&J=8&p=vara&d=varb%20varc

I have this so far, but I'm pretty confused about combining the info.  The hard part I'm finding is that each item that the person might pick from the list will have a different T=# value.

```
<script>
      var vara = document.getElementById("PPL");
      var varb = document.getElementById("DT");
      var varc = document.getElementById("TM");

</script>
```

This is the HTML form I have set up in the body of the page:

```
<FORM onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<Select TYPE="TEXT" NAME="PPL">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</Select>
<INPUT id="DT" TYPE="TEXT">
<SELECT id="TM" TYPE="TEXT">
    <option selected="selected" value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
    <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
    <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
    <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
    <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
</Select>
</FORM>
```

Below the form I have a table of items, and each of those needs to have a link tied to a graphic that when they click it will take the first part of the URL that is specific to that item, and combine it with the variables in the format listed above, and then open the new webpage in a new tab.  I've seen some posts around concatenating variables to make a URL, but I haven't been able to figure it out exactly, and they all seem to create the URL as function in the script.

EDIT:  I've figured out a link that opens the page and appears to have strung together the elements correctly, but I can seen in the destination URL that I'm getting null values for the variables I tried to define with the form.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.websiteurl.com/website.aspx?T=12345&J=8&p='+vara+'&d='+varb+'%20'+varc);return false;">
```

Edit (11/28/2013):  I tried changing the code approach a bit and used the below function, with the below HTML line to call it up.  It works to pull up the right page on the website I'm referencing, and the number I'm passing to the function is working correctly, but the other variables still show us as "undefined" in the completed URL.

```
    function OTCheck(IDnum)
{
u = 'http://www.website.com/websites.aspx?T='+IDnum+'&J=8&p='+vara+'&d='+var+'%20'+varc
return u
}
```

The item I'm linking from is in a table (hence the  tags):

```
<td><a href="javascript:location.href=OTCheck('21790')">Link</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` gets just the element, not value inside it. Fix:

```
  var vara = document.getElementById("PPL").value;
  var varb = document.getElementById("DT").value;
  var varc = document.getElementById("TM").value;

  document.getElementById("link").onclick = function() {
    window.open('http://www.websiteurl.com/website.aspx?T=12345&J=8&p='+vara+'&d='+varb+'%20'+varc);
    return false;
  }
```

Then change your html to this:

```
<form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<select id="PPL">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
 <input id="DT" type="text" />
 <select id="TM" type="text">
 <option selected="selected" value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
 <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
 <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
 <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
 <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
</select>
</form>

 <a href="#" id="link">This is link</a>
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I added the .value to each of the variable statements, but now instead of getting "NULL" in the resulting URL, I'm ending up with "undefined".  Do I need to execute a function for it to retrieve the values form the form, or is just having the variable definitions supposed to be enough?

Comment: That could be because you are using it online javascript. Please see my edit.

Comment: Still isn't working I'm afraid.  Clicking the link just adds "#" to the end of the current URL.  It doesn't open the new page I need.  Also the number that follows T= needs to be variable depending on which of the items in the table is being click on.  Can I set that variable and then execute the URL in a single click?

Comment: Yes, you can set. You had some html errors in your html code. I fixed them, try now.

Comment: Still does the same thing unfortunately.  I caught that I didn't have the right ID on PPL late yesterday (had it as name in error), but fixing it didn't solve the problem.  I made the other adjustments you have in the above but same outcome.

Comment: Ok I have it working now.  Looks like there were 2 issues.  I had the script with the variable setting in the header where they were being defined before the forms ever actually existed, and were coming up as undefined.  I moved the script into the body just above the </BODY> tag and it was grabbing the initial field values fine, but not updating when they were changed.  I moved the variable setting into the function and it's now updating correctly and working perfectly.  Thanks for you help sorting out some of the issues! :)